# ExecJS::RuntimeError Rails 4 using react-rails gem

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, react-rails

I am getting an error when I startup my local server `rails s`

Error message:

> compile ((execjs):6633:19): SyntaxError: [stdin]:5:10: unexpected . (ExecJS::RuntimeError)

and line **6** in my `application.html.erb` is highlighted:

`<%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>`

**Gemfile**

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'


# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.2.1'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem 'sqlite3'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.3.4'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

gem 'therubyracer', '0.12.1'
gem 'execjs'
gem 'node', '~> 0.0.2'
gem 'react-rails', '~> 1.0'
# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug'

  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> in views
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'

  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
end
```

I am using react-rails gem to render my `@records` object.

in ***app/assets/javascripts/components/records.js.coffee***

```
 @records = React.createClass
        render: ->
            React.DOM.div
                className: 'records'
                    React.DOM.h2
                        className: 'title'
                        'Records'
```

Anybody knows why I am getting this error message ?

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem... CoffeeScript is very meticulous about spacing. I need to start the function with a one tab spacing like so:

```
  @Records = React.createClass
    render: ->
      React.DOM.div
        className: 'records'
        React.DOM.h2
          className: 'title'
          'Records'
```